# 3d plot of wave function

Tags: matlab, 3d, surf

How can I plot the wave function `n=a*cos(k*x-w*t)` in Matlab in 3D with simulation?
The code I used was:

```
k=0.05;
f=100;
w=2*pi*f;
a=1;
x=[-5:1:5];
t=[0:2:20];
n=a.*cos(k.*x-w.*t);
surf(x,t,n);
```

Answer (score 2):

To plot a surface you need a mesh of data. The `x,t` you created are just a line, there is just a single `t` for every `x`, but a surface has multiple `t` for every `x`.

If you change your definition of `x` and `t` to:

```
[x,t]=meshgrid(-5:1:5,0:2:20);
```

Your code runs and plots:

[image]

Comment: How can I add motion to this plot?

Comment: That is a completely new question @SauravAgarwal , please ask a new one.

Comment: @SauravAgarwal consider accepting the answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

In this example I have made the resolution better by adding points to `x` and `t`. In the animation I have changed the value for `k`, you can also change e.g. f.

**Example**

```
f=100;
w=2*pi*f;
a=1;
x=linspace(-5,5,50);
t=linspace(0,2,50);


for k = 0.05:0.01:2         % Change values of e.g. k
    n = a.*cos(k.*x-w.*t);  % Re-calculate n
    pause(0.02)             % pause to control animation speed
    s = surf(x,t,repmat(n,[length(t),1])); % Use repmat to make Z 2D
    title(['k = ',num2str(k)])

    % Just some nice settings for surf plot
    shading interp
    lighting phong
    camlight left; camlight right; camlight left; camlight right;
    colormap copper
    alpha(.8)
end
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. If it answers your question, please accept the answer by klicking the check sign by the vote buttons next to my answer :) I'd appreciate it.